# Azure DevOps On-prem 2019 can't create inherited process

Tags: azure, tfs, migration, devops

I'm trying to make a new process for my collection that I've had since TFS 2013? We've migrated every version since up to 2019 Update 1.1, we haven't moved past that yet since the latest wants windows server 2016 or newer.

If I make a new collection I can go into collection settings > Processes > Select a process right click and create inherited process fine

If I go into the project that is in the actual development collection (the original collection) > Processes > Right click on say Agile there is only New Team Project and Export as options.

Online everything said check your permissions, so I went into the collection settings > Security and project collections administrator and there is no Create Process, Delete Process or Edit Process permissions, if I switch to the test collection they are there. I assume this is because of the migration over time.

How do I get these permissions in the dev collection that we actually use? We haven't used boards, or work items because we always used JIRA for that but we are planning on transitioning from JIRA to native Azure DevOps only and want to get this set up with a custom process template.

Comment: Just noticed that the new collection is an "Inherited Process" and the old one is "XML" ugh... how do we migrate from XML to inherited?

Answer (score 0):

When your collection is migrated from TFS, it will continue to use XML collections.

If you want to  use  inherited process, you need to create a new Collection with  inherited process.

For more detailed info, you could refer to this doc:[Create a project collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/manage-project-collections?view=azure-devops-2020&preserve-view=true#create-a-project-collection).

> how do we migrate from XML to inherited?

I am afriad that there is no such method could meet your requirements on Azure Devops Server.

This feature exists in Azure Devops Service. You could refer to this doc: [Clone a Hosted XML process to an Inheritance process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/upgrade-hosted-to-inherited?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts).

According to the doc, this feature only exists in the **Azure Devops Service**. When you select azure devops server 2019 in the drop-down box in the upper left corner, you can directly see that it is not supported.

Here is a [suggestion ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/614232/bring-inherited-process-to-existing-projects-for-a.html) about this feature. Our product group has decided not to implement this feature on azure devops server.

> For those customers who wish to go to Inherited, you have the
> following choices.
>
> 1. Move to the Azure DevOps Service
> 2. Create a new inherited collection and continue your project work
>    within that collection